# Ford Fiest 2015 Menu button locked

Tags: ford, fiesta, tire-pressure-monitoring-system

I have a 2015 ford fiesta and the menu button does not work, the radio does, the OK button seems responsive.
Is there any kind of 'Child lock' on the menu button or other reason it might not work?
tried with engine off/on & all combinations

The tyre pressure warning came on after hitting a big bump in the road - hence the need to access the menu button.
But the menu button was dead - Driving the car caused it to activate.

No idea why.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: "Driving the car caused it to activate." Did you mean activate the tyre pressure warning or make the menu button work again (while driving)?